# Lookup helper in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a 'countries' object which I pass as part of the Handlebars context:

```
{
 'hk': {'name': 'Hong Kong', 'someotherprop': 'someothervalue'},
 'us': {'name': 'United States',  'someotherprop': 'yetanothervalue'},
 ...
}
```

I want to use the lookup Handlebar helper to find from the countrycode 'hk' the name 'Hong Kong'.

I can get the following object

```
{'name': 'Hong Kong', 'someotherprop': 'someothervalue'}
```

using the following Handlebars directive

```
{{lookup ../countries countrycode}}
```

but how do I now extract the name property from this object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently one can chain lookup calls using the subexpression syntax

```
{{lookup (lookup ../countries countrycode) 'name'}}
```

Comment: And, if you need to access more than one property, e.g. `name` and `someotherprop`, you can use `{{#with (lookup ../countries countrycode)}} {{name}} {{someotherprop}} {{/with}}` http://stackoverflow.com/a/42520682/1487413